# How to display a uint8_t as an integer or string?

Tags: c, type-conversion, avr-gcc, uint8t, teensy

I am trialling a function that converts decimal numbers to binary, and I want to see if it is working or not. The problem is I am writing it in C for a Teensy micro controller, and I don't have many of the basic operations like printf. I am using a library that can only send information to the LCD screen as a string or double, so my only way to check if this function is working is to send the binary number to the LCD screen as a string or integer (if the binary number was 1010, the integer number would be 1010, not 10).

The libraries I am able to use are:

```
stdint
stdio
avr/io
avr/interrupt
util/delay
stdlib
```

Does anyone know how this can be done using the above libraries only?

EDIT: Included code as per comment request. The code I have used to convert the decimal to binary is:

```
uint8_t dec_to_bin(void){
    int n = 100;
    long long binaryNumber = 0;
    int remainder, i = 1;

    while (n!=0){
        remainder = n%2;
        n /= 2;
        binaryNumber += remainder*i;
        i *= 10;
    }
    return binaryNumber;
}
```

Then in the main function I have:

```
uint8_t a = dec_to_bin();
sprintf(a, "%u");
```

This returns the error:  error: passing argument 1 of 'sprintf' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Sure you have `printf()`. You just need to make your own `FILE`-like.

Comment: If you have `stdio` you should have `sprintf()`.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, I started to learn C only weeks ago. I just want a way to convert it to a string somehow. Then I can display it fine. Barmar when I try to use sprintf I get "passing argument 1 of 'sprintf' makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: @david_10001 You're using it incorrectly. If you post your code we can help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I have included the code in my question.

Comment: Please, have a look into doc. [sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). (It's a C++ doc. but these functions are "borrowed" from standard C I/O library.) The first argument of `sprintf()` is the output buffer (which is missing in `printf()`. The following arguments are identical.) The next argument is the formatter. For each formatting sequence (e.g. `%u`) you have to provide an additional argument. So, this would work: `char buffer[10]; sprintf(buffer, "%u", a);` or `printf("%u", a);`.

Comment: "...so my only way to check if this function is working..." Why don't you simply launch the program in your debugger?

Comment: The dec_to_bin() function doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't have any sort of debugger for this unfortunately, or I don't know about one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for sprintf is

```
int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );
```

So if you want to convert your number into a string (and that is what sprintf does) you have to give it an array of char where to put the string:

```
char output[9];
uint32_t a = dec_to_bin(100);

sprintf(output, "%08lu", a);
```

That should solve your compile error.

The second problem is you dec_to_bin function. The return values does not matches the value you are returning.

```
uint32_t dec_to_bin( uint32_t n ){

    uint32_t binaryNumber = 0;
    uint32_t remainder, i = 1;

    //prevent overflow
    if ( n > 255) {
        return 0;
    }

    while (n!=0){
        remainder = n%2;
        n /= 2;
        binaryNumber += remainder*i;
        i *= 10;
    }
    return binaryNumber;
}
```

Comment: Since uint32_t has 10 digits, returning up to 10-bit "binary" is possible. So the overflow check can be (n > 1023) instead of (n > 255). In the original example, "long long", thus uint64_t was chosen to allow up to 20 digits. Obviously the sprintf code should/could be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I no longer have the compile error. However I can't see any text relating to the numbers in the terminal anywhere